# Why is there an additional "None" dimension in the tensor shape when uploading a dataset to Activeloop Hub?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, hub

I am trying to upload an image datset to [Hub (dataset format with an API for creating, storing, & collaborating on AI datasets)](https://github.com/activeloopai/hub). I only uploaded part of the dataset, however upon inspecting the uploaded data I noticed that there was an additional `None` dimension in the tensor shape. Can someone explain why this occurred?

I am using the following tensor relationship:

```
ds 
-> images (htype = image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `none` dimension is present because some of the images might have three channels and the others have four, so dynamic dimensions are shown as None.